# JavaFX: IllegalArgumentException when mouse is clicked any where on scene

Tags: java, javafx-2, mouseevent, illegalargumentexception

Hi I am getting `IllegalArgumentException` when I click on any Control or on empty space of the scene. Below is the stack trace. I cant write a method for each control's `MouseEvent`. Could you please suggest a solution to cancel this mouse event when I click on empty space in scene or on disabled controls.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem and finally found the answer. I am using the latest SceneBuilder to generate the FXMLs. When finished, I use the 'View/Show Sample Controller Skeleton' which nicely lists required @FXML fields and action routines.
My ListView for purchases had a `#purchaseLVClicked` routine set in the Builder's code tab. Unfortunately, the suggested handler routine was:

```
    @FXML
    void purchaseLVClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    // Do something
    }
```

See the problem? It's not the routine's ***name***---which matches---but the ***parameter*** which should be `(MouseEvent me)` instead of `(ActionEvent event)`
. When I fixed that, the problem was gone. The moral don't believe 'suggestions' without double checking them.

Comment: I had the same problem, thank you very much for clarifying that AcionEvent should be changed to MouseEvent. I am also using the 'View/Show Sample Controller Skeleton' as it makes development a lot easier

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I was doing the exact same thing as you.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your Scene is trying to call a method that doesn't exist, so you have to implement it or make the components stop trying to call this method.

So, you can both implement the method in the Controller or you can remove the reference to it in your `.fxml` file.

Comment: If i mention method name in fxml file,and it is not available in controller then it causes IllegalArgument Execption. I can remove it in fxml file. `By default for an fxml control event there won't be handling method mapped`(it shows null). In that case it should not throw exception. But its giving exception. There might be 100 controls in scene, You cant define methods for all events and for all controls.

Comment: @Sil Are you using Scene Builder? In the code tab it shows `null` for all the events?

Comment: Yes i am using scene builder.